# What is the scope of a user-defined literal?

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

Consider these two:

```
namespace X1
{
    A operator "" _x(unsigned long long i) { return A{i}; }
};

namespace X2
{
    B operator "" _x(unsigned long long i) { return B{i}; }
};
```

The `x` literal is defined twice, but one of them is defined in `namespace X1` while another is defined in `namespace X2`.

According to the C++ standard, can this code be compiled?

Comment: No, i couldn't do it in Visual C++, it does not support this yet.

Comment: I recommend to use http://ideone.com/ , http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ or something equivalent online compiler.

Comment: It doesn't compile, but not for the reason you think. Make the operator accept `unsigned long long` parameter rather than `int`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A user-defined literal is treated as a call to `operator ""`*`X`*`(...)` where *`X`* is an identifier (for example, `_x`) and the `...` depends on the form of the user-defined literal. Lookup of the appropriate user-defined literal operator then proceeds according to the usual rules for unqualified lookup; **[lex.ext]**:

> 2 - A *user-defined-literal* is treated as a call to a literal operator or literal operator template (13.5.8). To determine the form of this call for a given *user-defined-literal `L`* with *ud-suffix `X`*, the *literal-operator-id* whose literal suffix identifier is *`X`* is looked up in the context of *`L`* **using the rules for unqualified name lookup (3.4.1)**. [...]

The definitions of the `_x` literal only conflict if both definitions are made available for unqualified lookup by a `using` or `using namespace` declaration or by entering either namespace; the conflict is only problematic if a call to the unqualified operator is actually made.

```
{ using namespace X1; auto o = 5_x; }          // OK; o is of type A
{ using namespace X2; auto o = 5_x; }          // OK; o is of type B
{ using namespace X1; using namespace X2; }    // OK; operator "" _x is not used
{ using namespace X1; using namespace X2; auto o = 5_x; }  // ambiguous
```

It would also be OK if the `_x` were different types of user-defined literal operators e.g. if one were an integer literal operator and the other a float literal operator.

Comment: I'd just like to add that the corresponding `using` usage would be `using X1::operator"" _x;` and `using X2::operator"" _x;` in case anyone finds this question and is wondering.